# Why another array is replaced in julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

In the program below, I want to update `A` little by little and want to evaluate the difference between current `A` and previous `A`, which is stored as `A_old`, for each `i` loop. However, the program returns `0.0` as `dif` from second update, i.e. from `i=2`. I want it return `1.0` everytime. I investigate the cause and found that `A_old` is replaced as well in `ii` loop. Could anyone tell me why it is so and how to fix it?

```
using Devectorize
A=[0.0 0.0];
A_old=[0.0 0.0];
for i=1:10
    for ii=1:2
        A[ii]=A[ii]+1;
    end
    dif=maximum(abs(A-A_old))
    @devec A_old=A;
    println(dif)
end
```

Comment: I think you really intend to make `A_old` a `copy` of `A` instead of a reference to `A` (that is `A_old = A`, makes `A_old` a new alias for `A`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note `Devectorize` is essentially deprecated by the broadcast changes. One solution is to use `copy!`:

```
A=[0.0 0.0];
A_old=[0.0 0.0];
for i=1:10
    for ii=1:2
        A[ii]=A[ii]+1;
    end
    dif=maximum(abs(A-A_old))
    copy!(A_old,A)
    println(dif)
end
```

or if you're on v0.5 (which I'd highly recommend), the broadcasting syntax allows for easy in-place updating:

```
A=[0.0 0.0];
A_old=[0.0 0.0];
for i=1:10
    for ii=1:2
        A[ii]=A[ii]+1;
    end
    dif=maximum(abs(A-A_old))
    A_old.=A
    println(dif)
end
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it deprecated quite yet; that makes it sound more official than it is.  It is largely superseded… but it still provides value until the dot-operators also parse as fused broadcasts (which is slated for 0.6).

Comment: On v0.5 you can do `*.(x,y)` instead of `x.*y` in order to get the `.` fusion. I think if someone is just getting started they should just get comfortable with `.` and not worry about `Devectorize` because, even if it isn't "deprecated" quite yet, with the changes in Julia over the last year, there truly isn't a need for it (which is one reason why it hasn't been updated).

Answer (score 4):

When running into issues with macros, I highly recommend using `macroexpand` to make sure that it's doing what you think it's doing.  In this case, `@devec` doesn't do anything to `A_old=A`:

```
julia> macroexpand(:(@devec A_old=A))
quote
    A_old = A
end
```

See Chris' answer for other ways of writing this in order to copy the data.

Answer (score 2):

The standard "trick" which *avoids* copying is to interchange the two arrays with

```
Aold, A = A, Aold
```

This is actually interchanging which pieces of memory each  of these bindings (variable names) refers to.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this is not quite what was asked for in this question though. This is what's used when Aold should be updated in each step.